# Rendering a partial data series with a complete series using MUI X Line Chart

Tags: charts, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-charts

I'm using the MUI X Line Chart, and would like to achieve this:
[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faG3g.png)

But I can't find the right prop for it.
(renders a partial data series alongside a complete set)

Searching the documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77347079/22099179 - according to the maintainers, it's currently not possible to create a chart that renders a partial data series alongside a complete set.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stable release, you can use `null` values to specify that points do not exist, and set the `connectNulls` property to `true` to interpolate missing points.

More details in the docs:

https://mui.com/x/react-charts/lines/#connect-missing-points